# How to display list in functional component in react, listing data is fetching with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to list data which is coming from external site through axios. My code is

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Listing() {
  useEffect(() => {});

  const todo = axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
    .then(todo => {
      todo.data.map(td => {
        //console.log(td.title);
      });
    });
  console.log(todo);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        todo.data.map((tdd)=><li>{tdd.title}</li>);
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**How can I list data ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, add an empty`[]` as second argument to avoid repeated call of `useEffect`. Also its very important to add key on array iteration. Add interpolation also

Check this. `{list.map((tdd)=><li key={tdd.id}>{tdd.title}</li>)}`

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios' 

export default function Hello() {

    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
      axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((todo)=> setList(todo.data));
    },[]) 
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>                    
                {list.map((tdd)=><li key={tdd.id}>{tdd.title}</li>)}              
                </ul>
            </div>
        )        
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that we can display it without using hooks and state ?

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar if we are using functional component, hooks is the only solution. Or we can call the api in the parent component and pass the value to child component and list the item.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code snippet for you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Listing() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
     async getData(){
        const todo = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
        setData(todo.data);
     }
   getData();
  },[])


  return ( <div >
    <ul >
       {data.map((tdd) => <li> {tdd.title}</li>)}
    <ul> 
    <div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Listing() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then(todo => {
      console.log("todo: ", todo);
      setList(todo.data);
    });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        list.map((tdd)=><li>{tdd.title}</li>);
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is wrong implementation. It will execute `useEffect` in infinite loop, which will result in dead browser

Comment: Actually I forget componentDidUpdate part for useEffect yes, you should use it like this

`useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then(todo => {
      console.log("todo: ", todo);
      setList(todo.data);
    });
  }, []);`